# Linux Print Using Command acroread Layout Incorrect

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

At the moment we are using the command `cat file.pdf | acroread -toPostScript -shrink -rotateAndCenter | lp -s -dprintername` to print PDF files to a network printer. This is in a Linux (RedHat) machine with Adobe Acrobat 9.5.5 installed.

The problem we are facing now is the incorrect layout. The right and left side are cropped. This PDF file has specifically set the right and left margins to '5' points. Other PDF files with default margin values prints out OK.

But if I open the file using the GUI Acrobat Reader and print, it prints out OK. From the "Print"  dialog window, and then clicking "Properties", I can see the print command is `lpr -P ricoh-aficio-3030 -o Option_10=False -o Option_30=None -o Option3=False -o Option1=None -o Option_20=False -o Option_25=False -o ColorModel=Grayscale -o Resolution=600dpi -o PageSize=A4 -o PageRegion=A4 -o InputSlot=Auto -o Duplex=None -o Collate=False -o MediaType=Auto -o OutputBin=Default -o StapleLocation=None -o RIPrintMode=0rhit -o JobType=Normal -o Password=None -o UserCode=None`. I tried running this in the terminal, the alignment/layout is still not right.

What are the options in the command `acroread` to set the page scale to "Shrink to Printable Area"?

I have tried the `-scale` option. Setting the value to `50` deems no change at all.

I have also tried using the `lp` and `lpr` commands directly (without the `cat` and `acroread` commands) and putting in the necessary options such as fit-to-page, scaling, page-left/right, etc., but the printout is still the same.

Comment: This part is beside the point, but surely you don't need to `cat` the file in a pipe to `acroread`? Just give the filename as argument to `acroread`. You can actually most probably just give the file as argument directly to `lp`, which will convert it on the fly to a format the printer understands (CUPS can do this via e.g. `pdftops`, and some printers support PDF directly). See `man lp` for a list of available transformation options (scaling, rotating, etc.). Going directly to the final command will at least narrow down the complexity and thus might simplify finding an consistent approach.

Comment: I have updated my question. Using the `lp` and `lpr` commands directly shows the same results. Putting in the options has no effect neither.